# QT default project showing errors

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to the qt framework environment, last night I applied some examples that I found in a book and everything worked fine, but today when I started QT creator and tried to import my project again, it crashed several times. Now, when I create a project and try to run it, it shows a list of errors although I didn't do any change to it.

Tried to change the qglobal.h but that made alot of false errors again, tried to reconfigure but with no luck, I should also mention that the examples that come with the creator work and run.

I'm using qt-creator 5.4.0 community with gcc 4.6 on a linux x86-32 bit machine.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

the .pro file

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-01-19T13:57:12
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled1
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Here's the compile output:

```
13:57:28: Starting: "/home/user/Qt/5.4/gcc/bin/qmake" /home/user/untitled1/untitled1.pro -r -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug
13:57:28: The process "/home/user/Qt/5.4/gcc/bin/qmake" exited normally.
13:57:28: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
/home/user/Qt/5.4/gcc/bin/uic ../untitled1/mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../Qt/5.4/gcc/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../untitled1 -I../Qt/5.4/gcc/include -I../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets -I../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtGui -I../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtCore -I. -I. -I. -o main.o ../untitled1/main.cpp
In file included from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h:38:0,
                 from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/QMainWindow:1,
                 from ../untitled1/mainwindow.h:4,
                 from ../untitled1/main.cpp:1:
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qtabwidget.h:49:44: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QWidget'
 class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QTabWidget : public QWidget
                                            ^
In file included from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtGui/qpaintdevice.h:37:0,
                 from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtGui/qpixmap.h:37,
                 from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtGui/qicon.h:40,
                 from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qtabwidget.h:38,
                 from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h:38,
                 from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/QMainWindow:1,
                 from ../untitled1/mainwindow.h:4,
                 from ../untitled1/main.cpp:1:
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtGui/qwindowdefs.h:47:7: error: forward declaration of 'class QWidget'
 class QWidget;
       ^
In file included from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h:38:0,
                 from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/QMainWindow:1,
                 from ../untitled1/mainwindow.h:4,
                 from ../untitled1/main.cpp:1:
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qtabwidget.h:157:20: error: 'QShowEvent' has not been declared
     void showEvent(QShowEvent *);
                    ^
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qtabwidget.h:158:22: error: 'QResizeEvent' has not been declared
     void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *);
                      ^
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qtabwidget.h:159:24: error: 'QKeyEvent' has not been declared
     void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *);
                        ^
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qtabwidget.h:160:21: error: 'QPaintEvent' has not been declared
     void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
                     ^
In file included from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtGui/qicon.h:37:0,
                 from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qtabwidget.h:38,
                 from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h:38,
                 from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/QMainWindow:1,
                 from ../untitled1/mainwindow.h:4,
                 from ../untitled1/main.cpp:1:
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qtabwidget.h: In member function 'QTabWidgetPrivate* QTabWidget::d_func()':
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:964:95: error: 'd_ptr' was not declared in this scope
     inline Class##Private* d_func() { return reinterpret_cast<Class##Private *>(qGetPtrHelper(d_ptr)); } \
                                                                                               ^
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qtabwidget.h:168:5: note: in expansion of macro 'Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE'
     Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(QTabWidget)
     ^
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qtabwidget.h: In member function 'const QTabWidgetPrivate* QTabWidget::d_func() const':
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:965:113: error: 'd_ptr' was not declared in this scope
     inline const Class##Private* d_func() const { return reinterpret_cast<const Class##Private *>(qGetPtrHelper(d_ptr)); } \
                                                                                                                 ^
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qtabwidget.h:168:5: note: in expansion of macro 'Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE'
     Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(QTabWidget)
     ^
In file included from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/QMainWindow:1:0,
                 from ../untitled1/mainwindow.h:4,
                 from ../untitled1/main.cpp:1:
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h: At global scope:
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h:52:45: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QWidget'
 class Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QMainWindow : public QWidget
                                             ^
In file included from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtGui/qpaintdevice.h:37:0,
                 from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtGui/qpixmap.h:37,
                 from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtGui/qicon.h:40,
                 from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qtabwidget.h:38,
                 from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h:38,
                 from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/QMainWindow:1,
                 from ../untitled1/mainwindow.h:4,
                 from ../untitled1/main.cpp:1:
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtGui/qwindowdefs.h:47:7: error: forward declaration of 'class QWidget'
 class QWidget;
       ^
In file included from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/QMainWindow:1:0,
                 from ../untitled1/mainwindow.h:4,
                 from ../untitled1/main.cpp:1:
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h:191:27: error: 'QContextMenuEvent' has not been declared
     void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event);
                           ^
In file included from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtGui/qicon.h:37:0,
                 from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qtabwidget.h:38,
                 from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h:38,
                 from ../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/QMainWindow:1,
                 from ../untitled1/mainwindow.h:4,
                 from ../untitled1/main.cpp:1:
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h: In member function 'QMainWindowPrivate* QMainWindow::d_func()':
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:964:95: error: 'd_ptr' was not declared in this scope
     inline Class##Private* d_func() { return reinterpret_cast<Class##Private *>(qGetPtrHelper(d_ptr)); } \
                                                                                               ^
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h:196:5: note: in expansion of macro 'Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE'
     Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(QMainWindow)
     ^
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h: In member function 'const QMainWindowPrivate* QMainWindow::d_func() const':
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:965:113: error: 'd_ptr' was not declared in this scope
     inline const Class##Private* d_func() const { return reinterpret_cast<const Class##Private *>(qGetPtrHelper(d_ptr)); } \
                                                                                                                 ^
../Qt/5.4/gcc/include/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h:196:5: note: in expansion of macro 'Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE'
     Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(QMainWindow)
     ^
../untitled1/main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
../untitled1/main.cpp:8:7: error: 'class MainWindow' has no member named 'show'
     w.show();
       ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
13:57:30: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled1 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.4.0 GCC 32bit)
When executing step "Make"
13:57:30: Elapsed time: 00:02.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783123/qt-error-invalid-use-of-incomplete-type-class-qlabel

Comment: Nope, saw that already. I have 13 more errors down there two of them are being located in the qglobal file for using pointers out of scope. That code has been edited,  but here It's the default code that qt generates :)
in addition to that, everything worked amazing before the crashes.

Comment: May you have more than one Qt Version installed? Check if your Kits are setup correctly, start a ``make clean && qmake && make``. Try compiling a minimalistic app to see if the error persists.

Comment: I just have one qt version installed, did that nothing happened. As I said in the question, I tried the examples and they ran properly, but it always show errors when I make a new project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes after crashes some configuration files get corrupted, if you're running on a Linux machine, for some reason. Try to reset the configurations, if that didn't help try to reinstall.

Comment: Yeah, there's some bug reports saying the same thing on their website. Did that earlier this morning and everything is working just fine thank you :)